# Macro ternary comma expression causes warning when used as a statement

Tags: c, macros, ternary-operator

I have defined a macro to log NULL pointers. Because I have NULL checks in my code, the macro is a ternary that always returns the argument and calls a function if it is NULL.

This however causes a compile warning (gcc: `right-hand operand of comma expression has no effect`) if the macro is used outside of an if statement.
Curiously, clang doesn't produce a warning, even with -Weverything.

The solution I have come up so far is defining another macro that wraps the expression in an if without a body.

```c
#define NULLPRINT(X)                        \
    ((X) ? (X)                              \
     : (fprintf(stderr,                     \
                "%s:%u: %s: %s is NULL.\n", \
                __FILE__,                   \
                __LINE__,                   \
                __func__,                   \
                #X),                        \
        stacktrace(),                    \
        (X)))

#define IF_NULLPRINT(X) do {if(NULLPRINT(X)){}} while(0)
```

Is there a way to do this without macro duplication and avoiding the compiler warning?
Obviously without turning off the warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try casting it to `void`:

```
(void) NULLPRINT(...);
```

This generally suppresses warnings about unused values of expressions.

You could define another macro that hides this.